# Increse numberic value of primefaces outputlabel

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Here, XHTML code, in outputlabel invoiceNumber must increase every time and unique

```
<tr>
<td><p:outputLabel style="font-weight: bold;" value="Invoice No" /><br /> 
    <p:outputlabel value="#{invoiceBean.invoiceNumber}" /></td>
<td><p:outputLabel style="font-weight: bold;" value="Date" /><br />
     <p:calendar value="#{invoiceBean.date}" /></td>
</tr>
```

How it can possible ??

Comment: When should it increase?

Comment: when page load from server side

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the invoiceNumber property inside your invoiceBean is coming from some type of database, you can increment it in the PostConstruct. Simply add this method to you bean:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
   getInvoiceID()++;
   //You will have to set the update invoice value back to the db in order for it to    persist.

}
```